# CONTAR CELDAS CON COLORES EN PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, ciencia-de-datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Tengo que contar la cantidad de colores que aparecen en una fila de excel, es decir, por ejemplo, en la primera fila aparecen 5 celdas de color verde,2 celdas de color rojo, 4 celdas de color celeste y 1 celda de color azul, y del conteo anterior agregarlo en una nueva columna, para este ejemplo la columna 'M' o si es posible agregar el conteo de cada color en una celda especifica dentro de la misma fila, para este ejemplo se espera que M1 contenga: '5 verde', en N1: '2 rojo', en O1: '4 celeste', en P1: '1 azul', y así para las demás filas.
Observaciones:

1. El archivo de excel lo cargo en pandas con pd.read_excel() para convertirlo en dataframe
2. Para el ejemplo anterior no especifiqué un rango, pero se busca poder especificar un rango específico de celdas a evaluar es decir, por ejemplo J1:X8
3. Estuve checando el siguiente material: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47857112/get-excel-cell-background-color-in-pandas-read-excel pero es algo confuso ya que apenas estoy iniciando con pandas y las bibliotecas que ofrece python para excel.

Gracias de antemano:)

Comment: Deberías optar por `openpyxl` ya que es más especifica para manejo de archivos Excel. `pandas` solo es una librería para el manejo y análisis de datos.